# Android Awareness Api not compatible with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-play-services

#### Visual Studio Version:

14.0.25431.01 Update 3

#### Xamarin.Android Version:

7.0.2.42

#### Xamarin Forms Version:

Tried 2.3.3.193, 2.3.4.192-pre2 & 2.3.3.180.

#### Operating System & Version:

Win 10 Pro ver. 1607 build 14393.693

#### Google Play Services Version:

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Awareness ver. 42.1001.0

#### Describe your Issue:

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Awareness doesn't work with Xamarin Forms.

#### Error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2072,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2`

#### Steps to Reproduce:

Create a blank Xamarin Forms project & use Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Awareness as described in [Xamarin's blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/google-awareness-api-for-android-query-and-react-to-signals/).

Comment: I've set Target Framework v7.0. But debugging device has Marshmallow. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error often caused by dex methods count limits. You should turn on "MultiDex" support in android project settings. Also you should update ProGuard in Android SDK (see Xamarin.Android release notes - https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.1/)

Comment: Enabling Multi-Dex shows error: CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : error : Expecting class path separator ';' before '\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar' in argument number 8

Comment: I'm not using Proguard

Comment: Proguard used for Multidex

Comment: Also there are some issues with paths with spaces or special characters (for ex. if Android SDK located at c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\). As workaround you can try:
1) move (or create symbolic link) Android SDK to path without spaces and special symbols, i.e. move from "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\" to "c:\android\android-sdk\"
2) change Android SDK path in Xamarin settings in VS (Tools - Options - Xamarin - Android Settings - Android SDK Location)